# Detecting if a Property of an Object is an Object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, google-apps-script

I'm going to use JSON to stringify the value of a property of an object in order to store it as a Tag on Google Calendar through Google Apps Script. The value is actually a **double-nested `Object`** (see `extraAttributes` in `myObject`).

I have an Object that is built like the following:

```
var myObject = {
  "location": "somwehere",
  "date": new Date(),
  "numSomething": 20,
  "extraAttributes": {"used": true, "interval": 60, "internals": {"timer": 10, "visible": false} }
}
```

I tried to make it pretty and readable... anyway: myObject actually has anywhere from 20-40 properties, some of which are nested `Objects`. So here's the question:

Is there a way to notify if the value of a property in an Object is an object itself (would extra levels of nesting be an issue for this detection?)? The reasoning behind this is that I don't know how `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` will affect the other data (I've tested it on that one particular value of type Object and it worked fine), and also that I don't know how much of a performance impact that those two functions would have on my script if the properties being stored reach 20-40.

I would rather do a check to see if the value is an Object and stringify only that (would that also be inefficient?). Feel free to lecture me on Objects and nesting if this would cause major problems in the future ;)

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you saying that in order to reduce the number of key/value pairs in the resulting JSON, you'd like to avoid anything at the top level that isn't an object?

Comment: Hmm... I'm confused by you also :P I meant to say that I want to check to see if it is an Object before setting the Tag, because the only thing that actually needs to be `JSON.stringify`-ed are the values that are Objects. So anything that is a String, Integer, Date, etc. can just be tagged normally. The Object needs to be stringified, but I didn't want to do "screw it, stringify everything", I wanted to only stringify the values that *needed* it to be tagged correctly. Does that make sense? In the end, I completely forgot about `typeof`, and will be using that to accomplish the goal :)

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It now sounds like you want an object that has some properties *(the ones that have a nested object)* serialized to JSON, and you want to keep the rest as native JavaScript. I'm wondering what the point would be.

Comment: Crud, sorry. I tried to explain it as best I could. I'll try again!

Basically, I'm storing all the property/value pairs of an Object (`myObject` above) into Tags on Google Calendar Events. The Tags can be pretty much anything except Objects, functions, etc. 90% of the data in `myObject` can just be tagged normally, but if I want to retain the data that is stored in a *nested object* (`extraAttributes` above), then I need to stringify it. I wanted to avoid stringifying everything, so I wanted to check to see if the `typeof extraAttributes === 'object'`, so it can be serialized and tagged.

Comment: Oh, that's strange. It doesn't let you store nested objects? If you're testing all properties, be careful, because `typeof null === object; // true`

Comment: It is supposed to accept `String` as the key/value pair (Google Calendar), but evidently it accepts more than that. I tested everything, and Object was the only data type that got fuzzy and broken. So that was the only thing I needed stringify through JSON and parse on the other end when retrieving the data from the Calendar. But no worries about `null`, I set all the tags after all processing has been done, and the Object whose properties/values will be stored is built using data exclusively `!null` :) But thank you for the warning, I didn't know that! Care to tell me why `null === 'object'`?

Comment: `null === 'object'` is for historical reasons that most everyone regrets. There have been deep discussions by the ECMAScript standards board to fix this in future versions, but it has been pretty well rejected at this point. Too much code breakage if they fix it now. I see your issue better now. They're doing a `toString()` evaluation of each value, so you were probably ending up with `"[object Object]"` as a value.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was getting. I imagine there are server-side conversions going on. I really hate when stuff like that isn't transparent, and honestly Google's documentation (at least for Apps Script) is seriously lacking. With all that I've learned by trial and error using their services, I could write a book of documentation! But anyway, I understand how that would break a lot of code. It's unfortunate, because `typeof null` should `=== null`. That would actually be incredibly useful in my eyes, to check to see if a value is null. But I suppose for the moment `=== 'object'` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Javascript values, except functions and `undefined`, [can be serialized as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071833/34397).

To answer your question, see the `typeof` operator.

Comment: Well dang, I've seen `typeof` in various JavaScript questions on Stack Overflow... but that didn't even cross my mind and I couldn't tell you why! Well, hopefully someone else runs across this question in the future (wasn't on SO particularly before now), so I don't feel so silly for asking it :P

Answer (score 1):

Another way to check if something is an object instead of using `typeof` (which can be misleading in some cases — for example `typeof [] === 'object'`) is to use the Object constructor:

```
var foo = { id: 1 };
var bar = 'string';
console.log(foo === Object(foo)) // true
console.log(bar === Object(bar)) // false
```

Comment: I didn't know about the Object constructor, very useful! Would you say that using the constructor is preferred over `typeof`? I find the Object constructor to be more readable, but I wonder about the performance costs. Not like I have any system that really needs millisecond boosts, but it would be useful to know the difference in any case!

Comment: @ChrisCirefice, I actually use underscore.js (underscorejs.org) for pretty much everything and I typically use its type detection (for example _.isArray, _.isObject) for consistency. Internally, underscore uses the Object constructor for testing objects, which is where I learned this. The annotated source for underscore is super educational and I highly recommend reading through it.